# Running several batch-files in a batch-file

Tags: batch-file

**I'm making a batch-file which is supposed to run several batch-files. The problem is that it runs the first batch-file, and then quits**

```
echo "Running SharePoint.Access\buildPackageAndCopy.bat..."
call SharePoint.Access\buildPackageAndCopy.bat

echo "Running SharePoint.Admin\buildPackageAndCopy.bat..."
call SharePoint.Admin\buildPackageAndCopy.bat

echo "Running Sharepoint.Levels\buildPackageAndCopy.bat..."
call SharePoint.Levels\buildPackageAndCopy.bat
```

**I'm sure i have an enter-line between all the commands.
This is one of the batch-files I am running**

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

cd /d C:\src\SharePoint\
msbuild /p:IsPackaging=True
md c:\temp\_wsp
xcopy Core\bin\Debug\SharePoint.Core.wsp c:\temp\_wsp /y
xcopy Definitions03\bin\Debug\SharePoint.CustomDefinitions01.wsp c:\temp\_wsp /y
xcopy CustomLists02\bin\Debug\SharePoint.CustomLists01.wsp c:\temp\_wsp /y
xcopy Customs01\bin\Debug\SharePoint.CustomPresentation01.wsp c:\temp\_wsp /y
```

Comment: Is there an `exit` command in any of the batch files?

Comment: What is `msbuild`? Is it a(nother) batch file? Does the first batch have it?

Comment: msbuild is the build system for Visual Studio. The code i have pasted is from the first batch file i am running. Does not seem to have an exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the content of the first batch file and see if the second one now runs.  That way you'll know whether something in the first one is aborting it.

Comment: When i comment the first one, the second start, but closes before the third. So it has to be something about the batch-files which is making them close.

Comment: I'd start commenting out chunks to try and track down what is causing the abort.

Comment: Found the bug. Was an exit cmd in the last bat. Thank you.